# jquery 3d carousel

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery from few days..

Can anyone tell me why is it that the carousel on [this page](http://web.enavu.com/demos/3dcarouselwip/) works fine on firefox and chrome but not on IE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 142
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 142
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

Try using the newer Jquery [release](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)?

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js